# RealTek RTL810xE PCIe on Toshiba Satellite C55 issues

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

Having issues with setting up the wireless network. Ubuntu system settings says that there's "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". Downloaded the Ubuntu driver from the RealTek website but the terminal keeps giving me an error message and I'm fairly certain I'm not using the proper commands.

Posted below is the inxi -Fxz info:

> ```
> System:    Host: Freedoms Kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
>            Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
>            Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
> Machine:   Device: laptop System: TOSHIBA product: Satellite C55-C v: PSCP6U-02J01E serial: N/A
>            Mobo: FF50 model: 06F5 v: Type2 - Board Version serial: N/A
>            UEFI: INSYDE v: 5.20 date: 09/15/2015
> Battery    BAT1: charge: 24.6 Wh 81.9% condition: 30.0/38.5 Wh (78%)
>            model: Panasonic PA5185U-1BRS status: Discharging
> CPU:       Quad core Intel Pentium N3700 (-MCP-) 
>            arch: Airmont rev.3 cache: 1024 KB
>            flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 12800
>            clock speeds: max: 2400 MHz 1: 589 MHz 2: 650 MHz 3: 1012 MHz
>            4: 1160 MHz
> Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
>            bus-ID: 00:02.0
>            Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) driver: i915
>            Resolution: 1366x768@59.99hz
>            OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 405 (Braswell)
>            version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.2 Direct Render: Yes
> Audio:     Card Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Def. Audio Controller
>            driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
>            Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-23-generic
> Network:   Card-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
>            bus-ID: 01:00.0
>            IF: N/A state: N/A mac: N/A
>            Card-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCIE Fast Ethernet controller
>            driver: r8169 port: 1000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
>            IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
> Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1004.3GB (0.9% used)
>            ID-1: /dev/sda model: HGST_HTS541010A9 size: 1000.2GB
>            ID-2: /dev/mmcblk0 model: N/A size: 15.9GB
>            ID-3: USB /dev/sdb model: DISK size: 4.1GB
> Partition: ID-1: / size: 398G used: 6.7G (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
> RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
> Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0C mobo: N/A
>            Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
> Info:      Processes: 250 Uptime: 12 min Memory: 1546.5/3854.5MB
>            Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.4.0
>            Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your wireless adapter is here: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n. It requires the installation of a driver. The Realtek is ethernet, not wireless.

Comment: ...of course it is. Well, that certainly explains why I couldn't get it functioning. Glad it was an exceedingly simple oversight and not a bigger complication. Thank you.